# regex to exclude long string of numbers

Tags: regex, parsley.js

I'm using the following to as part of my validation for fields in a checkout form.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9)(,'-/\\&.#? ]*$
```

We've had trouble with some customers mistakenly adding their cc number in these fields and we'd like to exclude any string of numbers over 12 in a row to hopefully alleviate that problem.  How can I do that?

Comment: @Sergio - I chose the answer from The fourth bird because while the regex you provided seems to correctly disallow "string 123456789012 string" it still allows "string123456789012 string" (note: I removed the space after the first string). I needed something that would pick up on a 12 digit match anywhere in the field being validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that there are not 12 or more digits in a row:

[`^(?!.*[0-9]{12,})[a-zA-Z0-9)(,'-/\&.#? ]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/XFNPUh/1)

`(?!.*[0-9]{12,})` means:

- `(?!` Start negative lookahead

  - `.*` Match any character zero or more times
  - `[0-9]{12,}` Match a digit 12 or more times (If you want to match exactly 12 digits you could use `{12}`
- `)` Close negative lookahead

Answer (score 0):

This will match lines that do not contain 12-character strings:

```
^(?!.*\b[a-zA-Z0-9)(,'\-\/\\&.#? ]{12}\b.*).*$
```

[Sample online regex.](https://regex101.com/r/ZGsS9c/2) Note I used the bracket expression provided in the question but escaped dash `-` and slash `/`. Also use a quantifier `{12}`.